# How to convert old spring boot 2 security configuration WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter based to new Spring boot 3 securityConfig

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth

I have this spring boot 2 security class based on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
import com.example.springsocial.security.*;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.example.springsocial.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I would like to convert this into spring boot 3 version. As you see the previous one has tonnes of config and beans

Sample only

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/oauth_login")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .loginPage("/oauth_login");
    return http.build();
}
```

This baeldung link is promising, but need advice on what specific bits can be lifted (or all)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

Comment: The most simple OAuth2 client configuration I know is [with a starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#112-client). The same repo also contains a tutorial for [writing the conf without "my" starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-client).

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(c -> c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(c -> c.authenticationEntryPoint(null))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c
                .requestMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(c -> c.authorizationEndpoint(cc -> cc.baseUri("/oauth2/authorize").authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository()))
                                .redirectionEndpoint(r -> r.baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*"))
                                .userInfoEndpoint(u->u.userService(customOAuth2UserService))
                                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
                                );

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customUserDetailsService':